# Does the Quickening Pulse Require a save every round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bard

After maintaining the Masterpiece do all enemies still within range need to make a new save each round to avoid taking bleed damage(which doesn't actually behave like bleed damage based on the effect description)?

[Quickening pulse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/bardic-masterpieces/masterpieces/the-quickening-pulse-percussion-wind)

> Your driving notes cause unnatural heart rates in your opponents.
>
> Prerequisite: Perform (percussion) 7 ranks or Perform (wind) 7 ranks.
>
> Cost: Feat or 3rd-level bard spell known.
>
> Effect: You create a musical tempo that first mirrors your enemies’
>   heartbeats, and then quickens them to dangerous levels. When you
>   complete the performance, all enemies within 30 feet who can hear your
>   performance must save or take 1d6 points of damage as their pounding
>   heart causes them to sweat blood. Creatures that are immune to
>   critical hits are unaffected by this ability.
>
> Each round that you continue the performance adds another round to the
>   bleed effect. Abilities that extend the duration of a bardic
>   performance (such as Lingering Performance) affect this masterpiece.
>
> Use: 1 bardic performance round per round of bleed.
>
> Action: 1 standard action.

Answer (score 1):

The “bleed effect” that gets extended, to my reading, is

> all enemies within 30 feet who can hear your performance must save or take 1d6 points of damage

which includes making the saving throw.

But it is not very clear and it could easily go the other way. Honestly, this isn’t terribly well-written. There is a [thread on Paizo’s forums asking this question](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2oddx?The-Quickening-Pulse-Bard-Masterpiece), but it has no responses.

So you’ll have to talk to your GM. The description for this masterpiece simply seems to be... incomplete.

Comment: The save falls under the bardic masterpiece umbrella which is 10+1/2 bard level+cha mod Will save.  Though I won't deny that it like alot of the bardic masterpiece text is a mess.

Comment: @jneko Ah, I’ll fix that—wasn’t where I looked though I guess where it is makes sense. Double-checking, though, it doesn’t answer your question, though.

Comment: To me, it seems like they get one Save on the first round and no save if you continue the Masterpiece... of course there's no text to support that. I also love that there isn't actually a bleed effect until the second paragraph.

Comment: @ifusaso I think the real issue is that this is not a Bleed effect, in the sense of the monster ability. The first paragraph says it makes the targets 'sweat blood' - perhaps it was originally intended to be an actual bleed effect, and then changed.